# Lucene boost case sensitive match

Tags: lucene

Our client uses a few acronyms on its site.

For example, let's say STACK is an acronym they are using.

When they are searching for "STACK" (keyword), they want documents that match "STACK" exactly (uppercase) to be on top of the search results, instead of documents matching "stack" lowercase.

Is there a way to achieve this? Maybe through query boosting somehow?

I'm using the StandardAnalyzer at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

`public final class StandardAnalyzer extends StopwordAnalyzerBase`

> Filters StandardTokenizer with StandardFilter, LowerCaseFilter and
>   StopFilter, using a list of English stop words.

So you have no difference between 'STACK' and 'stack'. You could add the keywords again as StringField that exactly matches the keywords you search for and boost the keyword field.

Answer (score 0):

It is really hard to make any judgements about this one case (STACK vs stack). If all your acronyms are upper case, just exclude `LowerCaseFilter` from the analyzer chain. If some of your acronyms can contain dots or dashes (e.g. [Y.M.C.A.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y.M.C.A._%28song%29)), you probably need to use `WhitespaceAnalyzer` (instead of `StandardAnalyzer`) to ensure these are not split into multiple terms.

To me, boosting sounds superfluous here. Say if somebody enters a query closely matching the acronym, the relevant document will be ranked high anyway because of its similarity.